# Transpose multiple sheets to a single sheet

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub sbCopyRangeToAnotherSheet()
   Dim col As Integer
   col = 1
   For Each wks In Worksheets
      If (wks.Name <> "Sheet23") Then
          wks.Range("A1:z29").Copy Destination:=Sheets("Sheet23").Cells(1, col)
          col = col + 25
      End If
   Next wks
End Sub
```

When I use this code above, it just adds everything behind each other. But I need to transpose it and have each sheet displayed below the other instead of next to each other. What do I need to change to do this?

Comment: each sheet displayed below the other

Answer (score 0):

try this and let me know:

```
Option Explicit

Sub sbCopyRangeToAnotherSheet()

    Dim rngRange        As Range
    Dim rnglasRow       As Long
    Dim wksDestination  As Worksheet
    Dim wks             As Worksheet

    Set wksDestination = Sheets("Sheet23")

    For Each wks In Worksheets
        If (wks.Name <> "Sheet23") Then
            Set rngRange = wksDestination.Cells.Find("*", wksDestination.Cells(1, 1), xlFormulas, xlWhole, xlByRows, xlPrevious)
            If Not rngRange Is Nothing Then
                rnglasRow = rngRange.Row
            Else
                rnglasRow = 1
            End If
            wks.Range("A1:z29").Copy Destination:=Sheets("Sheet23").Cells(rnglasRow + 2, 1)
        End If
    Next wks

    'Release Memory
    Set rngRange = Nothing
    Set wksDestination = Nothing
    Set wks = Nothing

End Sub
```